# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, trying to list certain users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am dealing with main users (teachers) and their students. They share the user's `id` and the student's `teacher_id`. I want to list all the students that have the same `teacher_id` as the current user's `id`, so the user can see all their students. This is my code:

```
<% @students = Student.all %>
<% if @students[:teacher_id] == @current_user.id %>
<% @students.each do |students| %>
  Username: <%= students.username %><br/>
  Name:  <%= students.name %><br/>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I am getting the following error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

What is going on? The logic seems sound: if the `teacher_id` is the same as the `current_user` id, print the students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `[:teacher_id]` on `@students`, which is an `ActiveRecord` relationship. You can think about it as an array. You should rather call it on an individual student by moving the `if` inside the iteration:

```
<% @students = Student.all %>
<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <% if student[:teacher_id] == @current_user.id %>
    Username: <%= student.username %><br/>
    Name:  <%= student.name %><br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There are some improvements you can do:

1. Do not call Active Record query (`Student.all`) in view, move it to the controller.
2. Filter in AR query, not in application: `Student.where(teacher_id: @current_user.id)` instead of `Student.all` and checking hash value.

Finally you'll get

```
# controller:
@students = Student.where(teacher_id: @current_user.id)

# view:
<% @students.each do |student| %>
    Username: <%= student.username %><br/>
    Name:  <%= student.name %><br/>
<% end %>
```